# Is there a place to store per channel user state for gRPC services in .NET

Tags: .net, grpc

I am playing with .NET gRPC. I implemented a simple gRCP server.

I have a channel that will stay for a long time and over this channel. The server will get a lot of calls over this channel.

I want to store a state associated with this channel (to share it across all the calls).

I found that UserState is available on ServerCallContext. However, base on what I read (and tried). This state is persisted only for a call (which could be a long-lived call, but still just once call).

I am looking whether any place is available where I can keep a state associated with a channel (vs a call).